# Каретка в конец текста в QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Как переместить каретку в конец текста в QTextEdit?
Пример кода:

```
void MainWindow::on_mark_textChanged()
{
    if((ui->mark->toPlainText()).size() > 2)
    {
        QString str = ui->mark->toPlainText();
        str.chop(1);
        ui->mark->setText(str);
    }
}
```

Тут вводимый текст обрезается до двух символов, а каретка возвращается в начало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
QTextCursor cursor = myQTextEdit.textCursor();
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
myQTextEdit.setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Если это не сработает, поменяйте местами строки 2 и 3.

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14145202/9630063)